# How to read whole HttpResponse body as a String with Akka-Streams HTTP

Tags: akka, akka-http

I hava written a akka http client example,but i can not read HttpResponse body as a String,my code is below:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpResponse, HttpRequest}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import scala.util.{Failure, Success}


object TestHttp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val url = "http://www.baidu.com"
    println(url)
    val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = url))
    responseFuture.andThen {
      case Success(resp: HttpResponse) => {
        //println(resp.status.intValue())
        //println(resp.status.defaultMessage())
        //val aaaa = resp.entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _)
        //println(aaaa.value.get.get.decodeString("UTF-8"))
        //println(resp.entity.dataBytes.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"),maximumFrameLength = 256,allowTruncation = true)).map(_.utf8String))
      val entity = resp.entity.toStrict(5 seconds).map(_.data.decodeString("UTF-8"))
      println(entity.value.getOrElse("none value"))
      //nodeCount=JsonUtil.nodeCount(entity.value.get.get)
    }
    case Failure(ex:Exception) => {
      println("http request error:"+ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and the result is :

**http://www.baidu.com**

**none value**

who can tell me why? and how to write the code?
thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask in one spot at once, this question was [answered on akka-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/TA937TuRwHE) already, very quickly after it was asked.

Please the [ScalaDoc of `value` on Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future):

> If the future is not completed the returned value will be None. If the future is completed the value will be Some(Success(t)) if it contains a valid result, or Some(Failure(error)) if it contains an exception.

So you simply look into the Future before it had the chance to complete, so it's empty.

Instead use operations like `map` or `onComplete` to inspect it.